# Puppeteer not retrieving JavaScript rendered page

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am trying to load the product page using puppeteer but its not working.

```
    const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

async function start(){
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    
    await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0); 
    
    await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36');
    
    url = "https://www.coupang.com/vp/products/2275049712?itemId=3903560010"
    await page.goto(url, {'waitUntil' : ['load', 'domcontentloaded', 'networkidle0', 'networkidle2']})
    await page.screenshot({path: "screenshot3.png", fullPage:true})
    await browser.close();
}

start()
```

If we open this [URL](https://www.coupang.com/vp/products/2275049712?itemId=3903560010) it will load the page half and when we scroll down it loads rest of the page.

I tried using the scroll as well but it did not work.

Scroll function is following

```
    [const waitTillHTMLRendered = async (page, timeout = 30000) => {
    const checkDurationMsecs = 1000;
    const maxChecks = timeout / checkDurationMsecs;
    let lastHTMLSize = 0;
    let checkCounts = 1;
    let countStableSizeIterations = 0;
    const minStableSizeIterations = 3;
  
    while(checkCounts++ <= maxChecks){
      let html = await page.content();
      let currentHTMLSize = html.length; 
  
      let bodyHTMLSize = await page.evaluate(() => document.body.innerHTML.length);
  
      console.log('last: ', lastHTMLSize, ' <> curr: ', currentHTMLSize, " body html size: ", bodyHTMLSize);
  
      if(lastHTMLSize != 0 && currentHTMLSize == lastHTMLSize) 
        countStableSizeIterations++;
      else 
        countStableSizeIterations = 0; //reset the counter
  
      if(countStableSizeIterations >= minStableSizeIterations) {
        console.log("Page rendered fully..");
        break;
      }
  
      lastHTMLSize = currentHTMLSize;
      await page.waitForTimeout(checkDurationMsecs);
    }  
  };][2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run this headfully, I don't see that the page loads fully with the review content. It seems to be detecting the bot and blocking those reviews from coming through regardless of the scroll.

Using `puppeteer-extra-stealth` headfully avoids detection, but headless stealth is still blocked. I'll update if I can find a solution, but I figure this is at least a step forward.

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer-extra"); // ^3.2.3
const StealthPlugin = require("puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth"); // ^2.9.0
puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin());

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  const url = "https://www.coupang.com/vp/products/2275049712?itemId=3903560010";
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
  await page.waitForSelector(".sdp-review__article__list__review__content");
  await page.waitForNetworkIdle();
  await page.screenshot({path: "screenshot3.png", fullPage: true});
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close())
;
```

In the future, if you see `waitForSelector` timeouts when running headlessly, it's a good idea to add a `console.log(await page.content());` which will usually show that you've been blocked before you waste time messing with scrolling and other futile strategies.

See also [Why does headless need to be false for Puppeteer to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63818869/why-does-headless-need-to-be-false-for-puppeteer-to-work)

Comment: Thanks for the response. It does work. I added a scroll to load the reviews and make it completely autonomous. 
Can you tell me what are the general reasons when it does not work with headless.

Comment: That's a good question. I don't know a huge amount about the mechanics detection (my speciality is working within pages after they've loaded successfully), but for whatever reason, many bot detectors have a much easier time figuring out if you're a bot if you run headlessly than headfully. Probably a good research project and feel free to drop a link or add a [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) if you learn more or figure out how to bypass it headlessly.