# I am trying to get an h4 element text which is a child of divs using puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, automation, puppeteer

I am trying this code to extract an h4 which a child of 7 parent divs. like parent div, grandparent div from this [website](https://play.projectnebula.com/planet/1101). The h4 is **Claimed**.

It doesnt work because h4 isnt received.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
async function run() {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
    })

    var x = 1101;
    while (x !== 0) {
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.setRequestInterception(true);

        page.on('request', (req) => {
            if (req.resourceType() == 'image' || req.resourceType() == 'font') {
                req.abort();
            }
            else {
                req.continue();
            }
        });
        page.setDefaultTimeout(0);
        await page.goto(`https://play.projectnebula.com/planet/${x}`);
        await page.waitForSelector('h4');
        const elements = await page.$$("h4");

        let text = await (await elements[elements.length - 2].getProperty("innerText")).jsonValue()
        text = text.toLowerCase().trim();
        if (text == 'claimed' || text == 'on sale') {
            console.log(text, x)
            x += 1;
            await page.close();
        }
        else {
            console.log(x, text)
            x = 0
        }
    }
}
run();
```

I am trying to find an unclaimed planet, the unclaimed and claimed both are in **h4**. After working on 1 or 2 URLs. The code stops even though the planet is claimed because the h4 of **claimed** isnt fetched.there are almost 13 h4 in these pages. For first or second url all 13 are fetched but for next URL only 11 are fethced

Comment: You need to `await` all Puppeteer calls that manipulate the browser. For your second part, canonical is [Why does headless need to be false for Puppeteer to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63818869/why-does-headless-need-to-be-false-for-puppeteer-to-work)

Comment: `page.waitForSelector('h4');` before your first `goto` doesn't make sense. Navigate first, then wait for things to show up.

Comment: @ggorlen it doesnt work h4 is still not received

Comment: It [still](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74666569/how-can-i-access-a-h4-element-with-no-class-but-is-a-child-of-div-and-div-is-als#comment131792245_74666569) works for me if I run this headfully and use `waitForSelector("h4")` after the goto.

Comment: @ggorlen it works for 2 or 3 links after that it doesnt

Comment: In what way does it fail?

Comment: @ggorlen after going through 1 or 2 urls it doesnt fetch h4 **claimed** While it fetches other h4

Comment: You mean it falls into the `else` branch? I'm not entirely sure what your goal is, I guess. What's the script supposed to do? You want to loop forward starting from planet 1101 until you see a `claimed` or `on sale` planet?

Comment: @ggorlen yes. I am trying to find unclaimed planets. If a planet is not claimed then I want it to show me the planet which is not claimed but the problem is. The planet is claimed but the code stops and shows me the page because **claimed** h4 isnt fetched

Comment: using .then() after wait for selector solved the problem

Comment: Hmm. It's not good practice to mix `then` and `async`/`await`, so there should be no reason for `then` here--`await` does the same thing.

Comment: `await` and `then` are totally equivalent, just different syntactical ways to do the exact same thing. So it's cool you figured it out with `then`, but you could probably write whatever you wrote more clearly with `await`. Consider posting a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) with your final solution. I'll offer feedback if I see it.

Comment: I saw your solution. The only functional difference is `waitForNetworkIdle`, not the `then` you added which is superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

After `await waitforselector()` use `await page.waitForNetworkIdle();`

```js
while (x !== 0) {
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  // we need to enable interception feature
  await page.setRequestInterception(true);

  page.on('request', (req) => {
      if (req.resourceType() == 'image' || req.resourceType() == 'font') {
          req.abort();
      }
      else {
          req.continue();
      }
  });
  page.setDefaultTimeout(0);
  await page.goto(`https://play.projectnebula.com/planet/${x}`);
  await page.waitForSelector('h4');
  // await page.waitForSelector('h4').then(async() => {
  await page.waitForNetworkIdle();
  const elements = await page.$$("h4");
  let text = await (await elements[elements.length - 2].getProperty("innerText")).jsonValue()
  text = text.toLowerCase().trim();
  if (text == 'claimed' || text == 'on auction' || text == 'on sale') {
      console.log(text, x)
      x += 1;
      await page.close();
  }
  else {
      console.log(x, text)
      x = 0
  }
}
```