# Puppeteer login page protocol changed from HTTPS to HTTP

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I'm using Puppeteer to log into https://anthem.com/login. This is a valid URL (at least as of the time of this post). Somehow it's being changed to http://anthem.com/login.

I know this because the screenshot shows "Access Denied You don't have permission to access "http://www.anthem.com/login/" on this server. Reference #18.9a...."

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

function run() {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
            const page = await browser.newPage();
            await page.goto('https://www.anthem.com/login/');

            await page.screenshot({path: 'after-login.png'});
            browser.close();

        } catch (e) {
            return reject(e);
        }
    });
}
run().then(console.log).catch(console.error);
```

package.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "puppeteer": "^19.10.0"
  }
}
```

I tried this using wget and it stalled. Under FF, I saw that it logs a primitive HTML page, priming JS and other stuff, and lets the JS build the real login page. I'm not sure what's changing the URL, or if somehow it knows I'm an agent and wants to block this somehow. What are the best steps to make Puppeteer look like a human based web browser like Chrome?

FWIW, this page may be harder than average. There was some 49 network requests for this login page, including 3 HTML and 22 JS.

Comment: No need for that `new Promise`--Puppeteer already gives you one. See [What is the explicit promise construction antipattern and how do I avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it). Have you tried [changing the user agent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70936552/6243352)?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should delay or wait until network idle, it's possible there are HTTP redirects pending being handled.

```js
  await page.goto('https://www.anthem.com/login', { waitUntil: ['networkidle2'])
```

Comment: That was a nice attempt, but I got the same result. Also, there's already an await for the page.goto. I guess I would've thought things done after the await would mean the page was fully loaded and everything on the page would have been fully resolved.