# Puppeteer - Cannot select prices on hotel website

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

**Follow-up problem:** My selecting calendar date (from my `fill_stayDates` function is NOT working thus causing the "prices" to not be printed out.

Can someone please provide some guidance on what I need to change for my `fill_stayDates` helper function - it was previously working before but now it doesn't? How do I also incorporate START_YEAR and END_YEAR as well?

---

New code:

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^21.4.1

const constants = {};
constants.START_MONTH = 'Jan'
constants.START_DAY = '28'
constants.START_YEAR = '2024' // realize I should incorporate this to my code

constants.END_MONTH = 'Feb'
constants.END_DAY = '3'
constants.END_YEAR = '2024' // realize I should incorporate this to my code

const url = "https://www.hilton.com/en/";
const ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36";

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    // * select `false` if you want to run non-headless mode for testing
    headless: false
    });
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.setUserAgent(ua);
  await page.setViewport({ width: 1065, height: 10700 });
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});

  // fill in Where to?
  await page.type('[class="form-input w-full"]', "Seattle, WA, USA");  

  // Click calendar UI to select dates
  await page.click('[data-testid="search-dates-button"]');
  await page.waitForSelector('[data-testid="calendar-container"]');

  // ! I believe this is not working
  await fill_stayDates(page, constants);

  // Click Find a Hotel button
  await page.click('[data-testid="search-submit-button"]');

  // for price
  const sel = 'li[class^="border-border"] p[data-testid="priceInfo"]';
  await page.waitForSelector(sel);
  const prices = await page.$$eval(
    sel,
    els => els.map(el => el.textContent.trim())
  );
  console.log(prices);
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());


//* HELPER FX: click to the correct starting month
async function fill_stayDates(page, constants) {
    await page.waitForTimeout(3000); // for testing
    const findMonth = async (targetMonth) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        const month = await page.$eval('[id^="calendar-month-"]', (el) => el.textContent);
        if (month.includes(targetMonth)) break;
  
        const arrows = await page.$$(
          '[data-testid="calendar-container"] > [class="flex justify-between"] button:not([disabled])'
        );
        await arrows[arrows.length - 1].click();
      }
    };
  
    const chooseDay = async (day) => {
      await page.waitForTimeout(3000); // for testing
      const dayResult = await page.$$eval(
        'button[id*=day-] span:not([class*=sr-only])',
        (elements) => elements.map((element) => element.textContent)
      );
      const dayIndex = dayResult.indexOf(`${day}`);
      await page.$$('button[id*=day-] span:not([class*=sr-only])').then((el) => el[dayIndex].click());
    };
  
    await findMonth(constants.START_MONTH);
    await chooseDay(constants.START_DAY);
    await findMonth(constants.END_MONTH);
    await chooseDay(constants.END_DAY);
  
    // Close pop-up
    await page.click('[class="stroke-text"]');
}
```

---

**Original problem:** I am trying to webscrape the prices but for some reason I cannot target it.

Hotel website: [Hotel website](https://www.hilton.com/en/search/?query=Seattle,%20Washington,%20US&arrivalDate=2023-12-20&departureDate=2023-12-22&flexibleDates=false&numRooms=1&numAdults=1&numChildren=0&room1ChildAges=&room1AdultAges=&sessionToken=28e9683c-ac84-466b-97b0-b74b8f34fe2c)

I tried the following before and it worked but now it no longer works:

`page.$$eval('li[class^="border-border"] p[data-testid="priceInfo"]', elements => elements.map(el => el.textContent.trim()))`

```
const [prices] = await Promise.all([
    page.$$eval('li[class^="border-border"] p[data-testid="priceInfo"]', elements => elements.map(el => el.textContent.trim()));
]);

console.log('prices:', prices);
```

and prices just prints out [] (empty array)

Comment: What's the point of `Promise.all` when there's only a single promise in the array? You can await that directly. As for the main issue, as you are probably aware, Puppeteer needs to load the site properly before selecting elements. Can you share a [mcve] showing that important context code? Maybe you're not waiting for these elements to be visible. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your selector works OK for me when I wait for the elements to appear:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^21.4.1

const url = "<Your URL>";
const ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36";

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: "new"});
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.setUserAgent(ua);
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
  const sel = 'li[class^="border-border"] p[data-testid="priceInfo"]';
  await page.waitForSelector(sel);
  const prices = await page.$$eval(
    sel,
    els => els.map(el => el.textContent.trim())
  );
  console.log(prices);
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

Output:

```js
[
  '$116', '$205', '$132',
  '$148', '$209', '$111',
  '$153', '$115', '$174',
  '$199', '$115', '$161',
  '$149', '$132', '$107',
  '$122', '$99',  '$115',
  '$137', '$99'
]
```

Although this works, I'd use `'[data-testid="priceInfo"]'` as the selector, because it's specific enough to disambiguate the elements, but not overly specific. If the `<p>` elements become `<div>`s, or `border-border` is renamed or is no longer the first class in the ancestor `<li>`, then your current selector will fail. The more assumptions in the selector, the [more risk there is of any one failing, causing the whole selector to break](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anna_Karenina_principle). The rule with selectors is be *just specific enough* to disambiguate, then stop. Don't be *too* specific. The risk of not being specific enough is that you may grab extra elements, but that seems unlikely with a test id, which are generally more stable than styling classes and quite precise (won't lead to false positives).

See [Why does headless need to be false for Puppeteer to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63818869/why-does-headless-need-to-be-false-for-puppeteer-to-work/70936552#70936552) for motivation for the user agent header.

Finally, there's no need for `Promise.all` if there's only one promise in the array. You can `await` it directly.