# Zoom auto join using puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, automation, puppeteer, zoom-meeting

I'm trying to join the zoom meeting with puppeteer, but my code is unable to capture the type password element, can anyone please help?

This is my code

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer-extra");
const StealthPlugin = require("puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth");
puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin());


async function joinZoomMeeting(){
    let meetId = '773 2982 7579';
    let meetPassCode = 'cnm4Ac';
    let joineeName = 'Sj';

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        args: [
          "--disable-notifications",
          "--enable-automation",
          "--start-maximized",
        ],
        ignoreDefaultArgs: false,
      });

    const [page] = await browser.pages();

    await page.goto('https://app.zoom.us/wc/join')
    
    await page.waitForSelector('input[type="text"]');
    await page.type('input[type="text"]', meetId);

    // await page.waitForSelector('.btn-join btn btn-primary')
    const joinButton = await page.$('.btn-join')
    
    await joinButton.click()

    await page.waitForTimeout(5000);
    
    const passwordField = await page.$('#input-for-pwd');
    console.log(passwordField)
    // await page.type('input[type="password"]', meetPassCode);
    // await page.waitForSelector('input[type="text"]');
    // await page.tpe('input[type="text"]' , joineeName);
    // const passInput = await page.$('.preview-meeting-info-field-input')
    // console.log(passInput)
    // const passwordInputSelector = '#input-for-pwd';

    // // Type the password into the input field
    // await page.type(passwordInputSelector, meetPassCode);
    
}

joinZoomMeeting()
```

I've tried all the commented ways of capturing the element! But nothing worked!!

This is the element

```html
<input id="input-for-pwd" type="password" class="preview-meeting-info-field-input" autocomplete="off" required="" aria-invalid="false" aria-describedby="error-for-pwd" value="">
```

Please let me know, how to fix this, I'm stuck at this point, the code is capturing the first type meeting Id element in the first page, but in the second page it is unable to capture the type password feild.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue here is that the page has an iframe with most of the app in it. You'll need to select the iframe first, then make queries inside of it.

As with many websites, there are quirks, so I had to use `waitForFunction` that dives into the iframe to verify the presence of an element because the normal `waitForSelector` was timing out.

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^21.6.0

let browser;
(async () => {
  const meetId = "<your meeting id here>";
  const meetPassCode = "<your meeting password here>";
  const joineeName = "Sj";
  browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  const ua =
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36";
  await page.setUserAgent(ua);
  await page.goto("https://app.zoom.us/wc/join");
  const meetingInput = await page.waitForSelector('input[type="text"]');
  await meetingInput.type(meetId);
  const joinBtn = await page.waitForSelector(".btn-join");
  await joinBtn.click();
  await page.waitForFunction(`
    document.querySelector("#webclient")
      .contentDocument.querySelector("#input-for-pwd")
  `);
  const f = await page.waitForSelector("#webclient");
  const frame = await f.contentFrame();
  await frame.type("#input-for-pwd", meetPassCode);
  await frame.type("#input-for-name", joineeName);
  await frame.$$eval("button", els =>
    els.find(el => el.textContent.trim() === "Join").click()
  );
  await frame.waitForSelector(".join-dialog");
  await page.screenshot({path: "zoom.png"});
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

You can take more actions or block the script with a timeout or remove `browser.close()` if you want the window to stay open indefinitely.

Tips:

- [Avoid `waitForTimeout`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73676564/6243352). It's both slow and flakey.
- `waitForSelector` [returns its element](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/#not-using-the-return-value-of-waitforselector-and-waitforxpath) (disclosure: I am the author of the blog post), so better to use it than query it again with `page.$`, which isn't generally necessary.

Comment: Can you suggest me, how to carry this out in headless mode. Can it be possible to counter this iFrame issue in headless also?

Comment: by the way ,  thanks it worked for browser based function, still trying to work it out headless.

Comment: Have you tried [changing the user agent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70936552/6243352)?

Comment: Yeah, headless also worked, thanks mate!