# Unable to extract table information in puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I wanted to extract some information about S&P 500 companies from https://www.sec.gov/edgar/search/ using puppeteer for a small side-project.

Here's my code:

```js
const getData = async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    defaultViewport: null,
  });

  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto("https://www.sec.gov/edgar/search/#/category=custom&entityName=0001551152&forms=10-K%252C11-K", {
    waitUntil: "domcontentloaded",
  });

  const data = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const tableBody = document.querySelector('tbody');
    const records = [];

    // Example: Extracting text content from each row in the table
    tableBody.querySelectorAll('tr').forEach((row) => {
      const rowData = [];
      row.querySelectorAll('td').forEach((cell) => {
        rowData.push(cell.textContent.trim());
      });
      records.push(rowData);
    });

    return records;
  });

  console.log(data);

  await browser.close();
};

getData();
```

I am getting the tablebody but when I am not able to parse.

Comment: Incorporating a `page.waitForSelector('tbody')` right after your `page.goto` navigation ensures that the table is present and ready for data retrieval. This small addition can significantly increase the reliability and success rate of your scraping project, leading to more accurate and comprehensive data collection.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

1. The `tbody` selector is too general. There are 4 tables on the page, and the first one is not the data you're looking for. Add the `#hits` parent to ensure you're targeting the correct table.
2. Be sure to use `waitForSelector` to ensure that the table cell data is in the page before scraping it.

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^21.6.0

const url = "<Your URL>";

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: "new"});
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  const ua =
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36";
  await page.setUserAgent(ua);
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
  await page.waitForSelector("#hits td");
  const data = await page.$eval("#hits table", el =>
    [...el.querySelectorAll("tr")].map(e =>
      [...e.querySelectorAll("td")].map(e =>
        e.textContent.trim()
      )
    )
  );
  console.log(data);
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

See [Why does headless need to be false for Puppeteer to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63818869/why-does-headless-need-to-be-false-for-puppeteer-to-work/70936552#70936552) if you're curious about the user agent.