# await page.click crashes with a "No element found for selector:" on first launch with nodeJS

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

When trying to implement a click on a page DOM using an input selector, the app crashes randomly throwing an error "No element found for selector: input[value="Search"]" but when I run the app again immediately after the crash, it works as expected.

source

```
    const page = await browser.newPage()

    await page.goto('https://ebay.ca')
    await page.type('#gh-ac', '16-inch Macbook Pro 2023');
    await page.click('input[value="Search"]')
```

error log

```
        throw new Error(message);
              ^

Error: No element found for selector: input[value="Search"]
    at assert (/Users/christophermaduka/Desktop/puppeteer/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/util/assert.js:18:15)
    at CdpFrame.click (/Users/christophermaduka/Desktop/puppeteer/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/api/Frame.js:672:40)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async /Users/christophermaduka/Desktop/puppeteer/index.js:38:5

Node.js v18.12.1
```

The selector is on the DOM, so there is no issue there.

Could it be a DOM content-loading issue?

Comment: Please share a [mcve]--is your `browser.launch()` headless or headful? This works for me, even in headless. If you've run the script many times, the server may be throttling/blocking you. [Changing the default user agent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70936552/6243352) is a good general idea. Often, it's better to search by encoding the URI and navigating directly to the search results page, bypassing automating the search bar and saving a page load. Ebay also has an "email me for new results" feature to avoid scraping in the first place.

Comment: The elements are baked into the index HTML, so you shouldn't need to wait for them (but can't hurt just in case). It's also possible (if unlikely) that the site is serving an A/B test on you with a different set of elements. `console.log(await page.content())` can help debug when headless--you can make sure your element is really in the page.